# Generate new dictionary keys from old dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm quite new to Python and am having difficulties creating local variables from a dynamically created dictionary (i.e. for each iteration of the process I'm running, the dictionary may contain a different number of address items).

I have the following dictionary :

```
{"item['address1']": u"1 High Street", "item['address2']": u'FY3 9JH Blackpool', "item['address3']": u'United Kingdom'}
```

And would like to get a dictionary as follows:

```
item['address1'] = "1 High Street"
item['address2'] = "FY3 9JH Blackpool"
item['address3'] = "United Kingdom"
```

How do I go about doing this? Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: Where did that dictionary come from?  Might be easier to fix the problem upstream.

Comment: The thing you describe in your title is a horrible idea, but the thing you describe in your question body is actually fairly reasonable. It's not actually a variable number of local variables; this would be converting your input dict into a more sensible dict. It'd help to know why your dict looks that way in the first place, though.

Comment: If `item = {'address1' : u'1 High Street'}`, then `item['address1'] == '1 High Street'`

Answer (score 5):

If you can be sure about the content of your original dictionary and can't get it in the desired format in the first place, here's an idea using `re`.

```
>>> import re
>>> old = {"item['address1']": u"1 High Street", "item['address2']": u'FY3 9JH Blackpool', "item['address3']": u'United Kingdom'}
>>> item = {re.sub("^item\['(.*)'\]$", r'\1', k) : old[k] for k in old}
>>> item
{'address1': u'1 High Street', 'address2': u'FY3 9JH Blackpool', 'address3': u'United Kingdom'}
>>> item['address1']
u'1 High Street'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex, you have multiple options:

You could  `exec` pretty safely once you trust the data:

```
d = {"item['address1']": u"1 High Street", "item['address2']": u'FY3 9JH Blackpool',
     "item['address3']": u'United Kingdom'}
item = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    exec('{} = v'.format(k, v))

print(item)
```

Output:

```
{'address3': 'United Kingdom', 'address2': 'FY3 9JH Blackpool', 'address1': '1 High Street'}
```

`str.index`:

```
d = {k[k.index("'")+1:k.rindex("'")]: v for k, v in d.items()}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'address1': '1 High Street', 'address2': 'FY3 9JH Blackpool', 'address3': 'United Kingdom'}
```

Or just `str.strip`:

```
d = {k.strip("item[]")[1:-1]: v for k, v in d.items()}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'address2': 'FY3 9JH Blackpool', 'address3': 'United Kingdom', 'address1': '1 High Street'}
```